# How can I minimize these similar if statements in scala?

Tags: arrays, scala, loops, if-statement

I have an array in scala:

```
  var walls: Array[LineSprite] = new Array[LineSprite](26)
```

And then I have these if statements:

```
if(curPlayer.intersects(walls(0))) {
handleCollision
updateLives(-1)
}
if(curPlayer.intersects(walls(1))) {
handleCollision
updateLives(-1)
}
if(curPlayer.intersects(walls(2))) {
handleCollision
updateLives(-1)
}
if(curPlayer.intersects(walls(3))) {
handleCollision
updateLives(-1)
}
if(curPlayer.intersects(walls(4))) {
handleCollision
updateLives(-1)
}
if(curPlayer.intersects(walls(5))) {
handleCollision
updateLives(-1)
}
if(curPlayer.intersects(walls(6))) {
handleCollision
updateLives(-1)
}
if(curPlayer.intersects(walls(7))) {
handleCollision
updateLives(-1)
}
if(curPlayer.intersects(walls(8))) {
handleCollision
updateLives(-1)
}
if(curPlayer.intersects(walls(9))) {
handleCollision
updateLives(-1)
}
if(curPlayer.intersects(walls(10))) {
handleCollision
updateLives(-1)
}
if(curPlayer.intersects(walls(11))) {
handleCollision
updateLives(-1)
}
```

...

How can I, instead of having a separate if statement for each item in the array that calls handleCollision and updateLives(-1), make it so that I can only have one if statement for all the items in the array?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you really want `handleCollision` and `updateLives` to be called multiple times if multiple walls are intersected? If not, you should use `if (walls exists curPlayer.intersects) {handleCollision; updateLives(-1)}`

Comment: I've seen 2nd year CS students do this in Java. There are actually people, who don't know what a loop is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should solve you problem

```
walls.foreach(w => if (curPlayer.intersects(w)) {
  handleCollision
  updateLives(-1)
})
```

I you want you can also use shorter solution with underscore

```
walls.foreach(if (curPlayer.intersects(_)) {...})
```

It wont give you anything but a more concise syntax

Comment: Yes, exactly what I was trying to do. Thank you!

Comment: If a player is at a corner intersecting two walls should they really lose 2 lives? That's an unusual game mechanic.

Comment: @JamesIry Sorry, but i know nothing about this game =) I've just showed how the author can reduce the number of ifs in his code